# cmake not able to find hdf5 library using FindHDF5

Tags: cmake

Do you guys have anby examples that uses FindHDF5 in its cmake?
the documentation does not tell how to call this function. FindHDF5() 
gives error that Unknown CMake command "FindHDF5"
I have 3.7 cmake installed on the machine
Thanks for your helps
Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's

```
find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED)
```

The keyword `REQUIRED` is not necessarily required.

In general, if you look at the documentation for FindXXX, you can import it with `find_package(XXX)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just wonder why this FindHDF5 does not work on its own ? https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindHDF5.html

Comment: It's this one, but it's not a function you can call like this :) Not so intuitive, I agree.